# How to get rid of left space in Gridview

Tags: asp.net

I added a LinkButton into an ItemTemplate for GridView and now I have a strange space all down the left of the gridview.  Wasn't there before I added link button.

Thanks for any help! Please see the link for pic:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out adding a CSS entry and setting the link button to it cured this:
    .fullwidth
        {
            width:80%;
            margin-left: 0;
            margin-right: 0;
            padding-left: 0;
            padding-top:0;
            padding-bottom:0;
            padding-right: 0;
            display: normal;
            text-align: left;
        }